# Bootstrap: form-group and select height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using a ready-made template. In the form I created, the "books" selection box is not the same height as the other boxes. How Can I Solve This?

```
https://codepen .io/Rheago/pen/oNeEbXG
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the select padding on y axis like this but it is not exact.

add py-2 to the class

```
<select class="form-select py-2" id="kitaplar" 
        name="kitaplar"
       placeholder="Kitap seçiniz..."
      required>
   <option>
      <option>Tester 1</option> 
 </option>
     </select>
```

or you can change it on the css file but it will not be responsive

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved with the following "class".

```
.formxselect
{
padding-top:.4rem;
padding-bottom:.4rem;
padding-left:1rem;
font-size:1.25rem;
border-radius:.3rem;
}
```